# Change orientation of view on device rotation using Autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I need to change position of squared view on device rotation using autolayout in storyboard. Please refer below picture for better understanding of problem.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have idea about trait variations you can designed a storyboard file in two different way like one for portrait and one for landscape i have created a demo what you explained in your question via images.

[PLEASE CHECK THIS DEMO APPLICATION](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y8HlN8IX6gH03eJyouP5sFdk3c-ncltt)

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard set the portrait layout in compact width regular height(wC hR) and landscape layout in regular width compact height(wR hC).

This will handle the positioning of the objects in different orientation.

Edited:
When you add a constraint to wChR it gets added to all layouts. So double click the constraint and install it only to wChR. Then go to wRhC add needed constraints and install it only to wRhC. In case of common constraint like height, width you can select the layout by double click of constraint and set different values if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have tried that but it will not give result like this. That is not changing the position of square.

Comment: can you please tell me how it appears on orientation change.